# jQuery replace element to input with value

Tags: jquery, button, edit

I'm working on a edit button that when I click on I can edit some elements in my page by an input field. So If I click the elements with the class .editable had to be change to an input field, and the value must be the text in the element. And when I click on the save (edit) button again, the value must be changed to the new one.

(I know I must save the new data in a database but thats not important. This page works like an example how the edit button must work).

This is for example my html:

The edit button

```
<li>
    <p><strong>Phone number:</strong><span class="editable">Some text which can be edited.</span>
</li>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$("#edit").click(
   function() {
      $("#edit").text('Save');
      $(document).find('.editable').each(function() {
         $(this).replaceWith("<input>");
      });
});
```

Comment: Where is this `#edit` button on your HTML?

Comment: Oops.. I haven't place them between the code signs. But the button is in my html like: `<div id="edit">Edit</div>`

Comment: why are u using .each, there is only one .editable class than why to iterate

Comment: Found it somewhere and tried to let it work with this code. I'm just started with jQuery so have to learn a lot of new stuff.

Comment: You can have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/t7LXt/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('editing') != '1') {
        $this.text('Save').attr('editing', 1);
        $(document).find('.editable').each(function() {
            var input = $('<input class="editing" />').val($(this).text());
            $(this).replaceWith(input);
        });
    }
    else {
        $this.text('Edit').removeAttr('editing');
        $(document).find('input.editing').each(function() {
            var div = $('<div class="editable" />').text($(this).val());
            $(this).replaceWith(div);
        });
    }
});
```

**[See a Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vh5GR/)**